# Conditional formatting cells if part of their value equals ANY value of another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have data in the `A` and `B` column. `B` column's data is sorta like the date in the 'A' column, but not always. For example:

```
A
Football
golf
running
baseball
House
bluehouse
New York

B
ball
house
Los Angeles
Bukarest
```

I need to search the `A` column for the values in `B` to check if they are there(including part of the value, such a 'ball'). If a row matches, I need to change the row's background colour in `A` to red or something.

What function do I need to use, and how?

I have tried with =match but it matches the full value and not part values

Answer (score 0):

Without using VBA to loop through checking for matches, the best I can come up with is having 1 conditional formatting rule for each value in `B`.

1. Select the cells you want to format (column A)
2. In conditional formatting select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"
3. Enter `=ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$1,A1))` for the formula
4. Set the format to whatever you want
5. Repeat steps 1-4 for each cell in `B` that you want to match